# B4a Listview how change color of Divider (seprator)

Tags: android-listview, basic4android

in Basic4Android i really need to change the color of Divider of Listview

cause my theme is Grey and the divider seems to be have a very similar color and cant be seen at all

how can i do this

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:divider="#FFCC00"`. Do not forget to put `dividerHeight="4dp"` as well.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#FFCC00"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks so much for reply

i`m so sorry but is this code works in Basic4android ?? i`m really new in android app design,  your code seems work in Eclipse 

how can i use this in B4A ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sub which should do the thing. You will need the Reflection library for that.

```
Sub SetDivider(lv As ListView, Color As Int, Height As Int)
   Dim r As Reflector
   r.Target = lv
   Dim CD As ColorDrawable
   CD.Initialize(Color, 0)
   r.RunMethod4("setDivider", Array As Object(CD), Array As String("android.graphics.drawable.Drawable"))
   r.RunMethod2("setDividerHeight", Height, "java.lang.int")
End Sub
```